# Why can't I answer question about gender pronouns?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, answers

I found [Am I conveying disrespect if I omit my gender pronoun from a conference nametag?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123994/am-i-conveying-disrespect-if-i-omit-my-gender-pronoun-from-a-conference-nametag) through the Hot Questions list. I was interested in posting an answer, but I don't see the answer box. I have 101 reputation here, but there isn't supposed to be a reputation minimum for posting answers. I also see answers from people with 41 and 17. Are there extra restrictions because it's a hot question or because there are already lots of answers (13)?

Someone else with reputation = 101 posted this comment, implying that they're having the same problem: "I don't seem to have the permissions, so I'll comment my answer."

Is it because most of my reputation is just the association bonus? That doesn't count towards answering protected questions, but the question in question is not protected, at least not when I view it:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience; Protected questions should now show up as such: [Protection banner missing when I don't have enough rep to answer; closed and locked banners appear in wrong spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322971/protection-banner-missing-when-i-dont-have-enough-rep-to-answer-closed-and-loc/323286#323286)

Comment: Thanks. The message with the explanation why I can't answer is perfect.

Answer (score 6):

The question is protected. As you seem to know what that means, you are probably thinking to yourself *it doesn't look protected, there is usually a notice*. You would be correct, but somebody broke something ...

[Protection banner missing when I don't have enough rep to answer; closed and locked banners appear in wrong spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322971/protection-banner-missing-when-i-dont-have-enough-rep-to-answer-closed-and-loc)

Comment: Yep, that's clearly the same bug. Unfortunately, we can't close this as a dupe, since it's on [meta.se] and this is [meta.academia.se].

Comment: That's OK. We'll keep track of it and let y'all know when it's fixed. Thanks so much for reporting this, @Barmar and sorry for the confusion it's caused. :)

Answer (score 1):

That question is [protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), which means you need to have certain rep to answer it. The association bonus doesn't count for that calculation.

Comment: Why don't I see the box saying "This question is protected" below the question?

Comment: @Barmar - refresh the page, maybe you loaded it a while ago? The question has been protected for a few hours now.

Comment: @Barmar - also, scroll down... the protection notice is near the bottom of the question, not the top.

Comment: I've refreshed several times, including with DevTools open (it's set to disable cache when open). looked at the top and bottom and used the browser's search function.

Comment: I even tried disabling AdBlock Plus in case the protected message was a false positive.

Comment: @Barmar it is right after the user name info and right before the comments. If it is not there, screen shot it and I will tag the question [tag:bug] so a CM looks at it.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. I've been here long enough that I know what a protected question looks like.

Comment: @Barmar yup, but I wanted to have a picture to show the people who can figure out what is going wrong. Thanks for the edit.